# ICS files on blackberry

Tags: blackberry, icalendar

I'm sending ICS files to Blackberry phones, and when you open the mail I get the following error on the phone:

> application/X-rimdevicecalendar, that when opened, the BlackBerry smartphone states this attachment type cannot be viewed on your device.

I found in the blackberry [knowledge base](http://btsc.webapps.blackberry.com/btsc/viewdocument.do?noCount=true&externalId=KB19700&sliceId=1&cmd=displayKC&dialogID=40304&docType=kc&isLoadPublishedVer=&stateId=40306&docTypeID=DT_SUPPORTISSUE_1_1&ViewedDocsListHelper=com.kanisa.apps.common.BaseViewedDocsListHelperImpl) the problem, but I could not fix it. Does anybody knows how to fix it? How I should send the ICS files?

Comment: Is there a programming question here?

Answer (score 0):

**.ics** files are the calendar event files for Apple's iCal calendar software.  Some other apps support this file type, but not all ... and some of the ones that do have some problems doing so.

You have at least a couple choices, depending on how these calendar event files are being generated and sent.

1. you could try sending them as .vcs files instead (and of course, reformatting the content as VCS files)
2. if you are going to stick with .ics files, [take a look at this CrackBerry.com thread](http://forums.crackberry.com/forum-f2/ics-calendar-attachment-workaround-237230/)

Basically, it looks like there is a workaround, where you might have to programmatically edit the .ics files, and replace this content:

```
METHOD:PUBLISH
```

with this:

```
METHOD:REQUEST
```

I haven't done this myself, so no guarantees.  But, that looks like a promising potential solution that you could try.

Comment: I already tried with the Method:Request, I will try with VCS Files. Do you have a page with this format? Because are the same for me.

Comment: @elranu, what do you mean by *"are the same for me"*? did you try **VCS** files, and you got the exact same error?